# Problema al usar un tablelayout dentro de Listview

Tags: android, android-layout

Estoy utilizando un **adaptador** personalizado en el que tengo un **.xml** donde esta un `ListView` y otro **.xml** donde tengo mi vista.

En mi archivo vista ingrese un `TableLayouṭ` y dentro de ella `TableRow` para acomodar mis controles dentro, el problema es que cuando ejecuto mi Aplicación y llego hasta ese punto me muestra mi información como lista pero se pierde el evento TAP si presiono en algún **Ítem** de la lista ya no me responde.

Comment: Podrías agregar tu código para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Hugo es importante des más detalles por ejemplo tu layout de lista y vista que contiene los el3m3ntos así como el código que no funciona adecuadamente, por ejemplo intentas usar el evento tap o clic, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que se mezclan los tap.
a los items de tu lista agregales.

`item.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);`

y esto desactivará el touch de la lista y dará paso a lo que hay dentro. Claro podrias tener un problema moviendo la lista de arriba hacia abajo. Asi que fijate bien donde activas el código. Si quieres mas ayuda deberias escribir el código para que entendamos mejor. :)